# How can i give effect of Lowercase letters to uppercase letter(and Vice Versa) using my custom keyboard shift button using android Keyboard API?

Tags: android, keyboard, key, android-keypad

i create my own custom keyBoard with different Languages? I get help with sample android code, But i can't understand how the shift Button is working?

In my keyboard : When i click on any character without press of Shift button then it will print small character.
and When i click on shift button then All character are return upper case letter. and After that shift button can't give effect to return lower case letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe u can use `KEYCODE_CAPS_LOCK`. Implement : `android:codes="115"` in your keyboard xml, sorry, i'm newbie too..